# Objective C 2d array, Array subscript is not an integer

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsarray, 2d

I'm trying to use a 2d array in Objective-C but getting an error of Array subscript is not an integer.

```
NSUInteger grid[15][15];
NSUInteger x,y;

grid[x][y]=1;
```

I have tried changing from NSUInteger to NSInteger and int.

Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a value for x and y, or else you're not accessing any index...

```
NSUInteger grid[15][15];
NSUInteger x=1,y=2;

grid[x][y]=1;
```